# Using Mean Value Theorem to prove the following statement is correct

Tags: calculus

Prove by using Mean Value Theorem that 
$ax≤f(x)≤bx$ , given $f(x)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $a≤f'(x)≤b $ for all $x≥0$.

Comment: So just use the theorem to prove it. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can only recall the theorem it is just I do not know exactly how to apply it to prove this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, and since $f(0)=0$, we have for some $c\in (0,x)$ that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(c).$$
Using the bound $a \le f'(y) \le b$ for all $y \ge 0$, we get
$$a \le \frac{f(x)}{x} \le b$$
for all $x \ge 0$ and the result follows.